# Mongodb query document array field length without fetch the array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Suppose I have a collection with an array field:

```
{
  title: String,
  users: [String],
}
```

Now I need to query a list of documents from the collection, using only the length of `users` in each of it, without actual elements in `users` array (because it maybe large, it won't be worth to fetch them from db and count the length):

```
Collection.find({}).sort({ _id: -1 })
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Do you  want to count the elements inside the `users` array?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet yeah, exactly

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**`$size`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) aggregation operator to find the length of the `users` array

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": { "userLength": { "$size" :"$users" }}}
])
```

If you want to find all the `users` array length exists in the database

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "allUsersArrayLength": { "$sum": { "$size": "$users" }}
  }}
])
```

Comment: It will not affect the performance of the query. Only add a new key with every document. Better then "finding all the document" and check the length by iterating. And even most of the things a database can better do with respect to javascript code.